# Converting Pandas dataframe to specific JSON structure

Tags: python, html, json, pandas, dataframe

I am interested in obtaining a specific json structure from Pandas Dataframes that I haven't been able to achieve from anywhere.

The code

```
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[-1]
print(df)
#print(df.to_json())
```

The Output

```
  Howe center       1st & river        4th & river  
5    8:37 AM            8:50 AM            8:52 AM        
6    8:57 AM            9:10 AM            9:12 AM         
7    9:17 AM            9:30 AM            9:32 AM
```

The desired JSON

```
{
 "Howe Center":["8:37 AM", "8:57 AM", "9:17 AM"],
 "1st & river":["8:50 AM", "9:10 AM", "9:30 AM"],
 "4th & river":["8:52 AM", "9:12 AM", "9:32 AM"]
}
```

What I Get

```
{
 "Howe Center":{"0":"8:37 AM,"1":"8:57 AM",...},
 "1st & river":{"0":"8:50 AM, ...}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
#import json
my_json=json.dumps(df.to_dict('list'))
print(my_json)
```

---

```
{"How ecenter": ["8:37 AM", "8:57 AM", "9:17 AM"], "1st & river": ["8:50 AM", "9:10 AM", "9:30 AM"], "4t & river": ["8:52 AM", "9:12 AM", "9:32 AM"]}
```